# passing a string variables into a function ksh

Tags: unix, ksh

I'm trying to pass string variables inside a function (the bteq itself does work) but can't seem to get it to work. I try this:

```
td_instance="one"
user="usr1"
pass="pass1"
schemaName="schemaA"
tblName="tableA"
query="SEL '>'||COUNT(*) FROM $schemaName.$tblName"

query_td() { bteq .LOGON $td_instance/$user,$pass
DATABASE $schemaName;
 .set width 1000;
  .set titledashes off;
 $1;
.LOGOFF;
.QUIT;
.EXIT
}

echo $(query_td << EOF |grep '^>' |sed -e "s/^>//" EOF "$query")
```

and keep getting this error:

```
-ksh: .: syntax error: `)' unexpected
```

I've moved a bunch of compenents around but still can't seem to get it to work..I keep getting the same error when I move things around so not sure what is wrong here but I know something is....

---------UPDATE------------

so based on the comments below...I've tried to simplify it to make it easier to debug...I've got the function to this now...

```
query_td() {
bteq "$(cat $HOME/.tdlogon) DATABASE $schemaName; .set width 1000; .set titledashes off; $1 .EXIT"
}

query_td $query
```

but now it seems to run the

```
bteq "$(cat $HOME/.tdlogon)
```

but for some reason doesn't run anything past that portion of the function. It starts the bteq program and logs in, but then just sits in bteq waiting for the commands...

Comment: What program is supposed to be seeing the`DATABASE`, `.set`, `.LOGOFF`, etc. lines because the shell is seeing them and not understanding them. I'm assuming `bteq` is supposed to get them as commands? If so you need to actually feed them to `bteq`. You cannot just put them on the next line and have that work (the way it does when `bteq` is run and presents you with an interactive prompt.

Comment: yep, bteq will use those...so does each one of those need to be a variable? if so, how would I do the "."? Can I just put it all on one line in the function, would that work as well?

Comment: If `bteq` will read commands from standard input you can pipe the lines at it. If it accepts a series of commands to run as an argument then you can quote those commands to pass them as a single string. If neither of those is true you may need to plzy with `expect`.

Comment: Etan Reisner: I tried this....query_td() {bteq |LOGON $td_instance/$user,$pass |DATABASE $schemaName; |set width 1000; |set titledashes off; |$1; |LOGOFF; |QUIT; |EXIT
}....but no luck...as that written right?

Comment: No, that's not right. Pipes work the other way. You pipe data *to* the program that needs to get it. So you would want `echo ".LOGON ...." | bteq` or similar.

Comment: I'm getting fairly confused now...if i use echo, its not a function then, right? I was just using echo to see what the result of the function is, I eventually, want to pass the result of that function into a variable which then goes to antoher function...I tried writing the funciton like this, but dont think I got any closer....query_td() {".LOGON $td_instance/$user,$pass" | "DATABASE $schemaName" | ."set width 1000;" | ".set titledashes off;" | ".$1;" | ".LOGOFF;" | ".QUIT;" | ".EXIT" bteq
}

Comment: `".LOGON ..."` is a string. That string is not a command. When the shell tries to run it as one it fails. That string (command) does not take any input nor generate any output. `echo` is a command that takes its arguments and outputs them to standard output. Try `echo "foo" | cat` vs. `"foo" | cat` vs. `"echo" "foo" | cat`. You want what I wrote `echo ".LOGON ... .EXIT" | bteq` if `bteq` takes a series of commands from standard input.

Comment: There are a couple of syntax errors. Start to split the `{bteq` into `{ bteq`, and fix the `<<EOF`. (The ending `EOF` has stand alone on a single line.) Update that in the question and add the result.

Comment: fixed the bteq but confused by the EOF on a seperate line...I thought echo had to be on one line...what about the $query following it?

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I was able to get this to work...moved the EOF inside the statement...I think this is what you guys were refering too, right?

```
td_query () { bteq << EOF |grep '^>' |sed -e "s/^>//" 
$(cat $HOME/.tdlogon)
    DATABASE $schemaName;
     .set width 1000;
      .set titledashes off;
    $1
.LOGOFF;
.QUIT;
.EXIT
EOF
}
echo "the date is: " $(td_query "SEL '>'||current_date;")
```